# Show that $K \neq F(a)$ for any $a \in K$.

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, finite-fields

Let $k$ be a field of characteristic $p >0$, let $K=k(x,y)$ be the rational function field over $k$ in two variables, and let $F=k(x^p,y^p)$. Show that $K \neq F(a)$ for any $a \in K$.

For $a \in K$ $a=\frac {f(x,y)}{g(x,y)}$ but how to show that this does not generate $x,y$ individualy?

Comment: I would rather start with an $F$-basis of $K$, namely the $p^2$ elements $x^iy^j$ with $0\le i<p$ and $0\le j<p$, and take a single element of $K$ expressed as an $F$-linear combination of these.

Comment: but how to conclude next? the element seems to be dificult to handle.

Comment: Take its $p$-th power, which now lands in $F$. Conclude that you’ve found the minimal polynomial of your suspect element. And so on.